# Watermark as image Behind the Image using Imagick in php

Tags: php, imagick

I am using the Imagick in php to display the watermark(image) behind the image but cannot. It get display on the front of the image

MY Code is :-

```
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("watermark.png");  
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
$wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
$iWidth = $im->getImageWidth();
$iHeight = $im->getImageHeight();
 if ($iHeight < $wHeight || $iWidth < $wWidth) {
     $watermark->scaleImage($iWidth, $iHeight);
     $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
        $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
    }
    $x = ($iWidth - $wWidth) / 2;
    $y = ($iHeight - $wHeight) / 2;
$im->compositeImage($watermark,imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,$x,$y);
```

What is have to do so that the watermark(image) to be displayed behind the image not in the front of the image.

Comment: If it's behind your image, you won't be able to see the watermark, because your image is in the way. So the watermark has to go on top. But you can make it almost transparent. That way, you can see both watermark and original image.

Comment: @Carsten That's not true. The watermark can go behind. If you use a composite image you can use compositive mix ins, such as imagick::COMPOSITE_DIFFERENCE  and subtract the source from the overlay. See here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php#imagick.constants.compositeop

Comment: @Layke True. Nice idea, didn't think of that. You should make that an answer. The basic point which I was trying to convey was "the watermark has to get to the top somehow". The most obvious solution for me was to slap the watermark on top of the image. But making the image permeable for the watermark is at least as good.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually have to edit the watermark image itself to make it almost completely transparent. When the images are mixed, there is no "in front" or "behind", it's more of a blending of the overlapping colors.

If you make your watermark barely opaque, then it will show up very subtly in the final image.